# constraint to bottom but allow keyboard to cover the view

Tags: android, scrollview, android-softkeyboard, android-constraintlayout

I have a view constrained to bottom of the parent. I also have text fields on top. how ever when the keyboard shows up, it will push bottom views up which will cover my text fields.

I have everything inside a scroll view, keyboard should cover the bottom view and I should be able to scroll to bottom to reach the bottom view.

Here is a simple example. I manually increased the height to reproduce the problem easier. I actually have more views, this is just for demonstration.

note that fillViewPort is also enabled.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_text_1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_text_2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/edit_text_1" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/bottom_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:background="@color/grey_500"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just simply need to put the `ScrollView` inside a `ConstraintLayout`
like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="180dp"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/edit_text_1"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="180dp"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/edit_text_2"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edit_text_1"/>
            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="160dp"
                android:id="@+id/bottom_view"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edit_text_2"/>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Actually `layout_constraintVertical_bias` did the trick! thanks for the answer. but your answer is currently wrong. Its not necessary to put scrollview in constraint layout. you also used `layout_constraintHorizontal_bias` instead of vertical one. nevertheless thanks a lot!

Comment: your update doesn't work for me. I'm testing this on API 26. but vertical bias set to 1 works like a charm.

Comment: that's interesting, I also tested on API 26, and it works perfectly

Comment: I probably missed something. your answer works fine but `bottom_view` is not at bottom of parent when keyboard is hidden. if you set `Bottom_toBottomOf="parent"` and also set `layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"`  for `bottom_view` it works the way i want.

Comment: you may want to give a black background so you can see its position.

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"` in the manifest for that particular activity